# Can someone explain this python behaviour?

Tags: python, linux, docker, package, centos7

I'm running py 2.7.18 in docker container , I'm using rh-python27 package in CentOS 7.

One of my project required `gitdb` package, When i run docker container it's complaining about gitdb is not found. but i'd mentioned that in my req.txt.

I troubleshooted in my docker container and found below behaviour. Can someone explain me the reason of this behavior. why `python` is pointing to `opt/rh/python27....` instead of `/usr/bin/python` ?

```
root@cicd-docker CENTOS7 /usr/bin > pwd
/usr/bin
root@cicd-docker CENTOS7 /usr/bin > ./python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Oct 23 2020, 13:34:23) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.__file__
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'
>>> import gitdb
>>> exit()
root@cicd-docker CENTOS7 /usr/bin > python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Oct 23 2020, 13:34:23) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.__file__
'/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'
>>> import gitdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gitdb
>>> exit()
root@cicd-docker CENTOS7 /usr/bin > sudo python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.__file__
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'
>>> import gitdb
>>> exit()
root@cicd-docker CENTOS7 /usr/bin >
```

Or what's the correct way to install python2.7.18 in centos docker?

Comment: Is this inside a Docker container? What base image are you using? How does your Dockerfile look? Why are you using an old (EOL) Python version?

Comment: My project required to be run on python 2.7.18. (sidenote: Currently we're migrating the code to the py 3.8.x)

Yes it's running inside a docker container, 
base image `centos:7`

Comment: For your second run, you seem to be running the python in `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin`. Try `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` then run `python`

Comment: @Philippe Sure, I will try this.

Comment: @Philippe This is what my path looks like.
`PATH=/opt/rh/rh-git218/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/rh/rh-git218/root/usr/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/root/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin`

Comment: You need to put `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin` after `/usr/bin`